# Tools to auto generating implicit wrappers in Scala

Tags: scala, code-generation, implicit-conversion

I am finding myself writing alot of boilerplate scala to add implicit class wrappers around modules of functions. For example, if I have this function defined for Seqs

```
def takeWhileRight[T](p: T=>Boolean)(s: Seq[T]): Seq[T] = s.reverse.takeWhile(p).reverse
```

I need to write this (completely deterministic) implicit wrapper:

```
implicit class EnrichSeq[T](value: Seq[T]) {

    def takeWhileRight(p: T=>Boolean): Seq[T] = SeqOps.takeWhileRight(p)(value)
}
```

This is one example of many. In every case the implicit wrapper ends up being mechanically derivable from the function it forwards to.

Is anyone aware of any tools or code generators that can automate the generation of such wrappers?

Answer (score 1):

You're using Scala 2.10's "implicit classes" already? The whole point (the only point) of that new syntactic sugar is to free you from having to write the implicit conversion method.

Comment: Yes, they free you from writing the implicit conversion method. But you are left with the choice of (a) implementing your functions inside the wrapper classes themselves, or else (b) adding forwarding logic for each method (as in my example above).  
One example of why (b) is preferable is that it allows:  
`import SeqOps._  
Seq(1, 2, 3).map(takeWhileRight(_ < 3))`

Comment: Sorry, meant something nested like this:
`import SeqOps._  
Seq(Seq(1, 2, 3)).map(takeWhileRight(_ < 3))`

Comment: Personally, I'd go with the implementation in the implicit class. Your example would become `Seq(Seq(1, 2, 3)).map(_.takeWhileRight(_ < 3))`, which seems quite acceptable to me.

Comment: You're probably right, Lachlan. But if so, it implies having many implicit class defns with complex implementations. How then to organise them? They can't be top-level, and yet it seems each should ideally live in it's own file for maintenance and unit testing reasons. Perhaps wrap each in an object of the same name, eg `object RichSeq {implicit class RichSeq[T](value: Seq[T]) { def takeWhileRight(p: T=>Boolean): Seq[T] = {...} }}`